# Which old work ceiling box?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, ceiling-fan, junction-box

I need to replace the ceiling box for a light (old work). The issue is that it is an old home with lath and plaster ceiling and drywall added later on top. The hole is right next to a beam. It looks like this:

[image]

Now I have the issue that the ears of the [normal old work box](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Carlon-1-Gang-18-cu-in-PVC-Round-Old-Work-Electrical-Box-B618RR/100404072) are not extending far enough to the back. They are made for drywall, so the ears can be put back maybe 3/4" ... but this does not cover the drywall, the plaster AND the lath. I have actually replaced the screws with longer one which improves the situation by a bit but now the ears flap in too early ... so they don't grip properly.

My favorite was actually the [Raco](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000HEIYHA) ... way more stury. However, the hole is right next to the beam so I don't think this works well either.

And, of course I do NOT want to create a new hole next to it and somehow patch the old one.

Is there any other old work box that works well in this situation?

Any recommendations?

Comment: Why not just use a metal box and screw it through the side into the beam?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact that could work … do you have a suggestion for a proper box though? Ordinary ones need open ceilings to screw to the beam

Comment: Maybe something like [this one](https://www.homedepot.com/p/4-in-15-8-cu-in-Steel-Octagon-Box-with-C-5-Cable-Clamp-54151N-25R/202601200)

Comment: How about a box like this, where you can just screw it to the beam or joist? https://www.homedepot.com/p/Southwire-Smart-Box-Adjustable-Depth-50-lbs-Ceiling-Box-Support-MSBRND/203343429

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a good one.